# How to truly align center of two elemnts with css?

Tags: css

I have a canvas with a circular image inside it that is placed inside a wrapper like this:

```
<div id="kaleidowrapper"><canvas class="kaleidoscope" height="1448" width="1448"></canvas></div>
```

.kaleidoscope is the circular image. The circular image radius is set based on the browser size so that the image can cover the entire background. The height and width are `2*radius` Like this

[image]

The wrapper has the following css:

```
#kaleidowrapper{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

By default my image get's positioned like this:
[image]

How can I position the image so that it's centered over the screen?

Comment: JSfiddle please. I would also say the the height/width of the rectangle is NOT 2*radius...from the images supplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use jquery for that. try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Uvq3/)

the JS:

```
var imgWidth = Math.sqrt(($("div").width()*$("div").width())*2);
$("img").css({
    "width": imgWidth,
    "position":"relative",
    "left":-((imgWidth-$("div").width())/2),
    "top":-((imgWidth-$("div").height())/2),
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is putting the upper left corner of image in the center of the page:

```
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

In order to get the image exactly centered, you need to appy a negative top margin of half the images height, and a negative left margin of half the images width.

```
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -???px;
  margin-left: -???px;
}
```